# Need Guide: what is the hashrate for ZOTAC P106-100 6GB GDDR5?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, hashpower, ethereum

One vendor is offering 20 GPUs and each $224.00 . Is it good card for mining ETH and what is the best hash for this? Please let me know your experiences. Is it worth to buy for ETH or other coins?

Answer (score 1):

The cards do not appear to have actually been released yet - so it is not possible to know their hashrate.

With that said, they SHOULD be about the same to perhaps a very little better than existing consumer-type GTX 1060 6GB cards, and should consume probably 20-30% less power at the same clocks due to the removal of all video circuitry and the probability that the parts of the die not used for mining on are also disabled by the BIOS or in the GPU itself.